# Getting feature that lies closest to point in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, routing

I am trying to perform routing with OpenLayers , GeoServer and MySQL.

In order to get the start and end points, I need to be able to get a feature of the node layer (which has point features) that lies closest to an arbitrary point I click on the map.

Does OpenLayers provide any functionality for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of comparison you can:

1. detect the point clicked
2. find the feature closest to this point
3. use the selectFeatureControl to programatically select this feature

see: http://jsfiddle.net/XfEmn/

(note, I use underscore.js _.min function, you could of course do this with a foor loop etc, the clue is to loop the features and get the one with the shortest distanceTo the clicked point)

Answer (score 6):

The solution is much easier nowadays.

[ol.source.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getClosestFeatureToCoordinate) has a function `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(coordinate, opt_filter)` to find the closest feature to a given coordinate.

A great example can be seen in the [IGC Data Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/igc.html)

```
const map = new ol.Map({...});
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({...});
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  var closestFeature = vectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(evt.originalEvent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OpenLayers has this functionality.
Its called SelectFeature Control. see docs [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html).

you should check how the following examples work(uses: OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature).

1. [OpenLayers Select and Highlight Feature Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html)
2. [OpenLayers Select Feature Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature.html)

You can get full list of examples [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) and apply keywords filter for `select` or `higlight`